# By declaring character type T, online judge shows Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    //variable declaration
    char T;
    int N, i;
    double f;

    scanf("%d",&T);

    //for loop for T times iteration
    for(i=1;i<=T;i++){
        //input number  for checking its square root
        scanf("%d", &N);
        //sqrt() library function for square root
        f= sqrt(N);

        //checking if N has int type square root 
        if(f - (int)f == 0)
            printf("YES\n");

        else
            printf("NO\n");
    }//for loop ends

    return 0;
}
```

Output in Code Blocks:

3

16

YES

15

NO

14

No

Online judge shows:
Result: runtime error (SIGSEGV)

The program will take input for number of lines to be printed. And in each line it will take an integer type number and checks whether the number is square root or not. If yes, then it will print 'YES'. Otherwise 'No'.

In my code, Range of T should be T<=100. So, I declared T as character data 
type. And I know the range of char is -128 to 127 or 0 to 255. I think it 
should work. I compiled this program in Code Blocks without any error. It 
gives right output. But when I compiled in online judge it gives runtime 
error (SIGSEGV).

Can anyone please help me why does it happen?
Thank you.

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Use `scanf("%hhd", &T);` instead of `scanf("%d",&T);`

Comment: or just use `int T;`

Comment: If I use scanf("%hhd", &T); then online judge shows wrong answer. But by using int T; it works. But, I want to declare T as char.

Comment: It may be a pre-C99 compiler.

Comment: Can you give Runtime error log. UVa and many other judge provide this.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&T);
```

Here `scanf` will try to store input into 4 bytes starting from address of T which will lead to segment fault as T is char so is allocated only one byte

Comment: Here in scanf ("%d", &T); if I give %c it will not give right output. Again in online judge it shows wrong answer.

Comment: If I change data type of T to integer type, And scanf("%d",&T); . Then online judge accepts my code.

Comment: you should also change scanf("%d", &N); to scanf(" %d ", &N); so that it ignores enter hit from previous input, it might be affecting outcome of your program

Answer (score 0):

Change `char T;` to `int T;`
Because char can not save value more than 255

Comment: Range of T should be T<=100. So, I declared T as character data type.